# ColdFusion built in web server, how to test from a domain

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

So I want to do this:

```
myapp.com -> localhost (ColdFusion local web server)
```

I can currently only do this:

```
localhost/myapp_folder/
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this using built in web server?

Comment: I don't think you can do what it seems you are asking using the built in web server. Do as Paul suggests and install Apache or IIS and it will be doable.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add

`127.0.0.1 myapp.com`

to your windows/etc/hosts file
(You'll need to do this as an administrator, so right click notepad and 'Use as administrator', browse to the file and edit that way).

This will make all requests on your local machine for myapp.com point to 127.0.0.1 (i.e localhost) - don't forget to remove it when you're done testing, as it will obviously stop you looking at the real site when you go live with it.

This will allow you to do myapp.com/myapp_folder/, but if you want to map /myapp_folder/ to the root of the myapp.com domain using the technique above, you'll have to use something more sophisticated like apache or IIS.